# R future_lapply with SLURM only running sequential

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, future, slurm

I'm using this SLURM script to initialize the job:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=11
#SBATCH --time=08:00:00
```

and an Rscript along these lines:

```
library

data

model_function <- lots of code

plan(multisession, workers=11)

sim_function <- function(sim_run) {
  
  future_lapply(future.seed = TRUE, vals, function(vv){

res <- model_function()

names(res) <- c(...long list of names...)

    dat <- reshape2::melt(res) %>% filter(L1 != "time") %>% mutate(
      time = Var1,
      Var1 = L1,
      L1 = NULL) %>%
      mutate(age_group = cut(Var2, custom_age_groups)) %>%
      group_by(Var1, age_group, time) %>%
      summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
      mutate(year = ceiling(time / 365),
             vv=vv)

    filename <- paste0(...,vv,".RDS")
    filename_Rt <- paste0(...,vv,".RDS")
    
    saveRDS(dat,filename)
    saveRDS(just_Rt,filename_Rt)

})

filename <- paste0(...,"_sim_run_",sim_run,".RDS")

consolidate_files(filename)

}

lapply(1:20, function(sim_run) sim_function(sim_run))
```

I can't seem to get this thing to run parallel.

I've tried lots of different plans:

```
plan(list(tweak(cluster, workers=1),tweak(multisession, workers=11)))
plan(list(tweak(sequential),tweak(multisession)))
plan(list(tweak(sequential),tweak(multicore)))
```

I've tried using the future_lapply instead:

```
future_lapply(1:20, function(sim_run) sim_function(sim_run))
```

All of these still seem to run sequential despite spinning up parallel sessions, is there some topology I'm not seeing?

The code works fine on my Windows desktop so maybe I'm not appropriately using SLURM?

Comment: (Author of future here): If you don't get an answer here, please bring this up on https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions.  Please try to provide a minimal reproducible example that others, including I, can use to reproduce.

Comment: I was hoping you might be around. I've been working on a reproducible example but I'm having trouble replicating the issue beyond my main model code.

Comment: You can set up a toy example where you report on `Sys.getpid()` from each future to convince yourself that you're actually running this in parallel in separate R processes.  See https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-3-topologies.html#example-a-remote-compute-cluster for an example.